# mysql_fetch_array() doing infinite loops

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I don't know why, a loop that should be finite, like

```
while ($noticia = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE deletada='0' ORDER BY id ASC")))
{
    // echo $noticia['blabla'];
}
```

is doing infinite loops, and the page doesn't load...

Why is it happening?

Comment: because on every while you are executing query so every time you will get data

Comment: mysql_* are deprecated so use `pdo` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE deletada='0' ORDER BY id ASC");
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $noticia['table_field'];
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated so don't suggest

Answer (score 4):

it can be solved by

```
  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE deletada='0' ORDER BY id ASC")

  while ($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($qry ))
    {
        // echo $noticia['blabla'];
    }
```

but `mysql_*` function is deprecated so use either pdo or mysqli

with pdo a simple simple [here is very simple pdo tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE deletada='0' ORDER BY id ASC");
$query->execute();
$row=$articlequery->fetch(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: @SergioToledoPiza if this answer help you than you can accept this answer by clicking the `right` mark below the voting pannel